# Creating slider image and text in a pure css from array output (WordPress PHP)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

**WordPress PHP**

The problem I am facing is that it breaks the images instead of putting them on each other. The images are not well aligned as it places them below each other. I am looping through the array to get the images and texts. More also, I am planning to create a pagination with dotted lines to show the represent each image and text in the slider

```
 <?php

 $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'home_page', // slug
     'posts_per_page' => 3, 

 );

 $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

     while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

         $my_query->the_post();
        // echo get_the_ID(); using the get_the_id to have the sense if a post exists
      //  print_r(get_field('slider')) ;
      echo '<div id="captioned-gallery"><figure class="slider">';
          $slider_array = get_field('slider');
          foreach($slider_array as $sub_array) {
            // print_r($sub_array['slider_text']);
                    echo '<figure>';
                    echo '<img src="'.$sub_array['slider_image'].'" />';
                    echo '<figcaption>'.$sub_array['slider_text'].'</figcaption>';
                    echo '</figure>';
          }
          echo ' </figure></div>';
           echo '<div class="sidebar"><p>'. get_field('side_bar').'</p></div>';
     }

 }

 // Reset the `$post` data to the current post in main query.
 wp_reset_postdata();
 wp_reset_query(); 
 ?>
```

**CSS File**

```
@keyframes slide {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#captioned-gallery { 
  width: 100%; overflow: hidden; 
}
figure.slider { 
  position: relative; width: 500%;
  font-size: 0; 
  animation: 30s slide infinite; 
}
figure.slider figure { 
  width: 100%; height: auto;
  display: inline-block;  position: inherit; 
}
figure.slider img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
figure.slider figure figcaption { 
  position: absolute; bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  color: #fff; width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem; padding: .6rem; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you are using a percentage unit (like your code: `width: 500%`), the child's full width (`width: 100%`) is the same with a parent width. seams like all of them have `width: 500%`.

For what are you doing this, you can use `vw` instead of `%`, I created a snippet from your code and solved your problem. **Note:** I think it's needed some `max-height` that I added in some classes.

```css
@keyframes slide {
0% { left: 0vw; }
20% { left: 0vw; }
25% { left: -100vw; }
45% { left: -100vw; }
50% { left: -200vw; }
70% { left: -200vw; }
75% { left: -300vw; }
95% { left: -300vw; }
100% { left: -400vw; }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#captioned-gallery { 
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
figure{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
figure.slider { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 0; 
  animation: 30s slide infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
figure.slider figure { 
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  position: inherit; 
}
figure.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
figure.slider figure figcaption { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: .6rem; 
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery">
  <figure class="slider">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/500px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" />
      <figcaption>Google</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/160px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" />
      <figcaption>Apple</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/96/Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg/440px-Microsoft_logo_%282012%29.svg.png" />
      <figcaption>Microsoft</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Facebook_Logo_%282015%29_light.svg/500px-Facebook_Logo_%282015%29_light.svg.png" />
      <figcaption>Facebook</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/400px-IBM_logo.svg.png" />
      <figcaption>IBM</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Though I have figured it out but I have a problem with the pagination